# Did Adorno think the effects of mass culture were uniform, or universal?

Tags: philosophy-of-culture, intelligence, adorno

Did Adorno think the effects of mass culture were uniform, or universal? In what way are its effects always the same?

The intellectual enjoying a detective novel is meant to "escape his own ego, seeking happiness in his identification with the unarticulated mob"; he is "delivered up to others" "disintegrating" so that he becomes comic and a worthless comic at that (as he "takes the side of those who laugh").

So says The Philosophy of New Music in drawing a parallel to Stravinsky's ballet [Petrushka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrushka_(ballet)) and its "fairground scene" orchestra. Without second guessing the answer, I wondered whether standardised responses to mass culture disintegrate everyone who engages in it, if the above is a standardised response, etc..

Comment: what's the difference between 'uniform' and 'universal'?

Comment: nothing @DennisKozevnikoff here. the comma was meant to show they mean the same

Comment: if that's the reason for the downvote @DennisKozevnikoff then please do reverse it https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192584/difference-between-or-and-or-or-with-a-comma-versus-or-without-a-comma

Comment: yes i did give you a downvote because i find your question confusing. i still don't understand it. effects being uniform / universal, and effects being the same? the same as what? what is the example supposed to illustrate?

Comment: if effects are universal / uniform across all people, then it effects are the same for everyone. i don't understand what the issue is here @DennisKozevnikoff the example is meant to be an example of how people respond to the mass culture. what is there not to get?

Comment: how can anything affect all people in the same way? can game of thrones or the beatles affect me and you the same way?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff i don't mean identical responses, i'm asking if we can categorise all responses as anything, as e.g. always corrosive. or whether, because we are sufficiently post modern or intelligent, we can consume popular culture ironically without being harmed or standardised by it. as an example

Comment: i don't see the problem here. river water is always wet, but we can't step in the same river twice. i think you're being unhelpful @DennisKozevnikoff

Comment: i agree i'm not helpful because i cannot answer your question since i still don't understand it

Comment: maybe it's an Adorno thing @DennisKozevnikoff he's difficult to understand without applying what he says to life itself (and with a certain amount of militancy). no worries